# iCalendar Method to reschedule appointent

Tags: rest, icalendar, zimbra

I am trying to get my zimbra server to reschedule an appointment via REST.
It is relatively straight forward, I have to post an ics with the updated date of the VEVENT maintaining the UID, incrementing the SEQUENCE and updating the DTSTAMP. I post the ics with curl and the appointment is updated. Easy-peasy.
Now if I hadd attendees (required participants) to this event then new invites need to be sent out to them. That is not happening. The event is updated in the organiser's calendar but not in the attendee's calendar.
I have read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446 but it is not clear what methods should be used here. A REQUEST is the obvious choice as per 3.2.2.1 but my understanding is that it is for the communication between the servers. What method should the organizer's client use when talking to the server?